# Getting ClassExceptionError when adding object to List<Object> w/Java

Tags: java

I'm just going to include the functions that I'm having a problem with -

```
private List<Object> chute = new ArrayList<Object>();

public void press(int value) {
    if(numOfButtons == -1) throw new IllegalArgumentException("No Construct Method Called");
    if (value >=0 && value < numOfButtons){
        if(productCosts.get(value)<= currentMoney && productStock.get(value) >= 1){
            change = currentMoney - productCosts.get(value);
            List<Integer> coinTypes_sorted = new ArrayList<Integer>(coinTypes);
            Collections.sort(coinTypes_sorted);
            getChange(change,coinTypes_sorted, coinTypes.size() -1);
            currentMoney -= productCosts.get(value);
            productStock.set(value, productStock.get(value)-1);
            chute.add(productNames.get(value));
            chute.add(change);

        }
    } else throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value is not in range of button selection");
}

   private void getChange(int money,List<Integer> coins, int iterator){
    if(iterator >= 0){
        int maxValue = Collections.max(coins);
        int indexOfMax = coinTypes.indexOf(maxValue);
        while (money >= maxValue && coinStock.get(indexOfMax) > 0){
            money -= maxValue;
            chute.add(new Coin(maxValue));
            coinStock.set(indexOfMax,coinStock.get(indexOfMax) -1);
        }
        iterator -= 1;
        coins.remove(Collections.max(coins));
        getChange(money, coins, iterator);
    } else return;
}
```

The problem I'm getting is on the line `chute.add(new Coin(maxValue))` in the `getChange` method.

The exception I get is:
*Edit added full stack trace -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: ca.ucalgary.seng301.vendingmachine.Coin cannot be cast to ca.ucalgary.seng301.vendingmachine.Pop
at ca.ucalgary.seng301.vendingmachine.parser.Parser.checkDelivery(Parser.java:54)
at ca.ucalgary.seng301.vendingmachine.parser.Parser.CHECK_DELIVERY(Parser.java:370)
at ca.ucalgary.seng301.vendingmachine.parser.Parser.Command(Parser.java:226)
at ca.ucalgary.seng301.vendingmachine.parser.Parser.process(Parser.java:190)
at ca.ucalgary.seng301.vendingmachine.Driver.<init>(Driver.java:17)
at ca.ucalgary.seng301.myvendingmachine.VendingMachineFactory.<init>(VendingMachineFactory.java:467)
at ca.ucalgary.seng301.myvendingmachine.VendingMachineFactory.main(VendingMachineFactory.java:461)
```

How is this possible considering that it is just a list of `Object` and not a list of `Pop`.

Edit*

```
 @Override
public List<Object> extract() {
    if(numOfButtons == -1) throw new IllegalArgumentException("No Construct Method Called");
    List<Object> temp = new LinkedList<Object>();
    while(chute.size() != 0 ){
        temp.add(chute.remove(0));
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Okay - Now all mentions of the `chute` object have been added.

Edit*

Here is Check Delivery Documentation

```
 * "CHECK_DELIVERY" "(" <INTEGER> { "," <STRING> } ")"
 *
```

- - This command is used to check whether your vending machine behaves as
- expected. This command does not communicate with your vending machine, but
- checks whether it has already delivered what is expected.
- - 
- **Purpose:**
- 
- The integer indicates the expected total value of all coins delivered (for
- example, as change). The sequence of strings indicates the kinds of pop that
- are expected to have been delivered.

---

#### Fixed

So essentially this isn't a fix, but he says that his parser is an early model so instead of looking for coins its just looking for integers. Sorry for really late check in.

Comment: Are you trying to add objects with different types to the ArrayList? You have `chute.add(productNames.get(value))` and also `chute.add(change)`. What are the types of these?

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace. It's hard to find a scenario where the exception is thrown from the ArrayList#add method. Do you actually see ArrayList#add in the exception stack trace?

Comment: Yes - Essentially in this program, I need to simulate a bit of what a vending machine is.  So the chute is something that will have coins and pops and everything that could possible pop out of the machine.  productNames.get(value)) is of type Pop.  and chute.add(change) is a total int value of change given, while I would like also to add the individual object Coin for each coin given.

Comment: Haven't you something like that in your code "chute = new ArrayList<Pop>();" where you change the object it is refering to.

Comment: We need the Parser code to see your issue. The cast exception comes from Parser#checkDelivery. It is not in the code you pasted.  The methods #press and #getChange are nowhere in the stack trace.

Comment: Bleh - That I don't have, my Prof doesn't want to provide it cause he feels its too complex and not needed. I will email him and see post any answer I get.

Comment: Again, we need to see the implementation of Parser#checkDelivery, that is where your issue is. Where do you see #extract in your exception stack trace?

Comment: @kRyan, what arguments does the checkDelivery method take? Just FWIW, you will make your life easier if you make the "chute" ArrayList typed for only one type and not Object. Putting a combination of Coin, Pop, and Integer into the same ArrayList is only asking for hard to debug trouble.

Comment: Have you try:private List<Coin> chute = new ArrayList<Coin>();

Comment: Added Documentation given for checkDelivery

Comment: @kRyan I need the code but my guess is that you are mixing up two collections. There is a collection for coins and another for the Pop that is delivered. It seems like you are allowing Parser to work on a collection that contains coins when what it really wants is the inventory of Pop.

Comment: you do realize that the crash is not in the posted code, right?

Comment: @robert_difalco, The problem is that he gave us an interface that he wants us to implement and the interface calls for a single returned list of List<Object>.  It sucks cause he doesn't give the parser code (Which would have been the first place I would have gone for an answer).   Also the Pop constructor calls for a single String Argument.

Comment: @kRyan you need to identify which in the stacktrace is part of your code.

Comment: @njzk2, Yes, I wasn't given the Parser code - so I was hoping that there was maybe something I didn't see.

Comment: @kRyan that does not change the fact that `The problem I'm getting is on the line chute.add(new Coin(maxValue))` is not consistent with your stacktrace. Either post the code that matches that stacktrace, or post the stacktrace that matches the code.

Comment: @njzk2, the reason I initially said its on that line chute.add(new Coin(maxValue)) is that the problem only occurred when I introduced that line.  I'm trying to get a hold of the code for the given stack trace but like I said the Parser Class code was not given to me.

Comment: how about `VendingMachineFactory`? or `Driver`?

Comment: how exactly are you communicating with the `VendingMachineFactory`?